# Lossless Predictive coding

Tags: huffman-code

Hi I have a problem implementing the following:

```
DPCM----> Entropy Coding
My DPCM predictor is 

AB
CX
X=0.75A-0.5B+0.75C


public static int[][] predictor(int[][] copy, int wt, int ht)
{

    int[][] error=new int[ht][wt];
    //error[0][0]=copy[0][0];
  for(int i=0;i<ht;i++)
  {
      for(int j=0;j<wt;j++)
      {
          if(j==0&&i==0)
          error[i][j]=copy[0][0];  
          else if (j==0&&i!=0)
              error[i][j]=copy[i][j]-copy[i-1][j];
          else if(i==0&&j!=0)
              error[i][j]=copy[i][j]-copy[i][j-1];
          else
              error[i][j]=copy[i][j]-(int)(0.75*copy[i][j-1]-0.5*copy[i-1]                 [j]+0.75*copy[i-1][j-1]);

      }
  }
```

I have implemented this and I store the errors in a 2d array.

After this I need to do Modified Huffman Coding (code book size of 128)
So what i dont get is modified huffman coding is to be done on the errors values? which can also be negative 
What does code book size mean actually? 
Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Modified Huffman Coding is used on fax machines to encode black images on white color. You will have two Huffman tables,one for black runs and one for white runs, which is not related with Mean-Square Error.Even though it may be related for it,purpose of using MSE is to eliminate negative values so using a simple error metric such as subtraction will not work. As you may have noticed, you will have less bit rate for black runs and more bit rate for white runs. Code word length means the size of each code vector,on the other hand, code book size means the number of vectors you have in your topology.